# Xmpp library for Visual basic language

Tags: xmpp, agsxmpp

https://xmpp.org/software/libraries.html

which `xmpp` library has to be used for VB.NET language, I haven't seen VB.NET language mentioned in language column? currently, I am using agsxmpp for C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any C# library from VB.NET transparently, just [add reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) to the that library in your project and you will see classes as they where written in VB.

And also you can use most of C libraries (if they work under Windows) via [P/Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)